# Simple way to setup MTA on FreeBSD only for PHP mail()

Tags: email, freebsd, mta

I need to setup mail server for sending from PHP scripts only. I'm not needed to receive email or sending it by another way. Preferable is the Postfix (it is easy than Sendmail, for example). Ssmtp is doesn't suit me.

Is there some manual or ready-to-run config for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

freebsd handbook is the best resource about your requirements:

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/mail-using.html

https://wiki.freebsd.org/SecureSSMTP

i prefer ssmtp

Answer (score 2):

ssmtp has the big disadvantage to loose mails if the mailhub server is not reachable.
there should be at least some spooler for this scenario.